# What is the difference between Gvim and Vim?

Tags: vim, gvim

Could someone please explain to me the differences between Gvim and Vim?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

GVim is Vim with a built-in GUI, whereas plain Vim needs a terminal emulator (like GNOME Terminal, for example) to run.

The built-in GUI provides several extra features to GVim. Borrowing from [a post in the Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2458/205):

> Some features that will *only* work with gVim:
>
> - Supports a much wider range of colors (RGB), while the terminal only supports 256 colors (see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/556480/24-bit-true-color-in-konsole/703891#703891) and [this](https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728)).
> - Some other more advanced graphical features, such as "wiggly lines" for spell checking, more flexible cursor shapes, etc. A terminal can
>     only do "blocks of monospaced characters".
> - Enables [mouse support](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/gui.txt.html#gui-mouse), if otherwise left alone (including [drag-and-drop](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/gui.txt.html#drag-n-drop) for files). Terminal Vim can also handle the mouse
>     quite well, but not drag-and-drop.
> - Offers a nice, [customizable](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/gui.txt.html#creating-menus) menu system, where each option has the corresponding Vim command listed.
> - gVim can offer you scrollbars which scroll the Vim buffer (and not the Terminal scrollback).
> - You can have popup ["balloons"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8534055/660921) (aka. "tooltips").
> - Many terminals do not provide true italics like gVim does.
> - Has [integrated font support](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27guifont%27).
>
> Secondly, even if you prefer using Vim, installing a GUI version may
>   offer more compile-time features than the version without, at least in
>   some distros (such as `clipboard` and `clientserver` support on
>   Debian-based system in `vim-nox` vs `vim-gnome`).
>
> Things gVim **doesn't** do:
>
> - gVim isn't a (full) terminal emulator, so starting external programs that use a lot of terminal features won't work very well. For example
>     try using `:!vim`, `:!mutt`, or `:!irssi` from gVim, or pressing <kbd>K</kbd>
>     over a word (which, by default, opens the manpage for that word). Also
>     [see this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4152/51).

Answer (score 3):

Both GVim and Vim are the same, the difference is that Gvim offers an interface that doesn't run in a terminal window. Basically, Gvim has GUI-like menus and toolbar.

Here are quotes from [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Which-is-better-Vim-or-gvim) that provide more information:

> VIM is designed for using the keyboard efficiently and not for using
> the mouse.
>
> Functionally there is no difference between VIM and GVIM. They both
> work the same and have same keyboard sequences. VIM does not need a
> Graphical User Interface (GUI) and uses terminal shell environment to
> provide text editing features. However GVIM (or MVIM on mac) uses X
> windowing system (like GTK+) to provide a desktop like window
> appearance to vim with all text editing features. Performance wise
> also both vim and gvim behave almost identically.
>
> Apart from this, there are few addition operations supported by GVIM
> like
>
> - More font and better text rendering support in gvim.
> - GVIM has additional menu and tool bars which vim lacks