# What are the default text editors in different flavours of Ubuntu?

Tags: text-editor

What are the default text editors (GUI and CLI) in different flavors of Ubuntu. what commands should we use to edit files with them?

[image: screensho]

---

*Behind the question*

I tried Kubuntu and want to try more Ubuntu flavors and other distros, but when I was in Kubuntu I tried so hard to run `gksu gedit /path/file.txt` which wont work because gedit isn't the default text editor in Kubuntu, it's kate. I'm glad `nano` was available. but if I want to try more flavors I must know what are the default text editors in various Ubuntu flavors

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58513/discussion-on-question-by-yoginee-pingale-what-are-the-default-text-editors-in-d). Please post any further discussion there. Comments will be deleted from this post with no warning.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I think Answers by [Muzaffar](https://askubuntu.com/a/913621/665251) and [Terrance](https://askubuntu.com/a/913616/665251) serves your need. One thing to note is that you can install any of these text editors in any flavors.

---

### GUI Text Editors

#### [Gedit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/gedit)

Default in:

1. [Ubuntu Desktop](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
2. [Ubuntu Kylin](https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/ubuntu-kylin)
3. [Ubuntu Budgie](https://ubuntubudgie.org/)
4. [Ubuntu Unity](https://ubuntuunity.org/)

Gedit is certainly the most famous text editor in the Ubuntu world. Gedit is also available for [Windows](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win64/gedit/) and [MacOS](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/mac/gedit/). To install Gedit on any Ubuntu flavor use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gedit
```

To open a file with gedit:

```
gedit /path/to.file.txt
```

#### [Kate](https://kate-editor.org/)

Default in:

1. [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/)
2. [KDE Neon](https://neon.kde.org/) (not an official Ubuntu flavor)

it is also available for [Windows](http://download.kde.org/stable/kate/Kate-setup-16.08.3-KF5.28-64bit.exe). Like many KDE apps it has a load of [features](https://kate-editor.org/about-kate/). To install, run:

```
sudo apt-get install kate
```

If you want the latest version of Kate, you'll need to [add a PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kate
```

To open a file with kate:

```
kate /path/to.file.txt
```

#### [Leafpad](http://tarot.freeshell.org/leafpad/)

Unlike Kate, emphasis of Leafpad is on simplicity and lightness, which is whole agenda of the [LXDE project](http://lxde.org/). It comes pre-installed on **[Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/)**. To install:

```
sudo apt-get install leafpad
```

To open a file with leafpad:

```
leafpad /path/to.file.txt
```

#### [Mousepad](https://github.com/codebrainz/mousepad)

Default in:

1. [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/)
2. [Ubuntu Studio](https://ubuntustudio.org/)

In philosophy, Mousepad is pretty similar to Leafpad. To install:

```
sudo apt-get install mousepad
```

To open a file with mousepad:

```
mousepad /path/to.file.txt
```

#### [Pluma](https://github.com/mate-desktop/pluma)

Pluma is a fork of Gedit which comes preinstalled in **[Ubuntu Mate](https://ubuntu-mate.org/)**. To install:

```
sudo apt-get install pluma
```

To open a file with pluma:

```
pluma /path/to.file.txt
```

**Note:** if you want to [edit files with root privileges](https://askubuntu.com/a/908703/665251), add `gksu` in front of a command, like this:

```
gksudo gedit path/to/file.txt
```

[It's best to avoid using it with Kate.](https://blog.martin-graesslin.com/blog/2017/02/editing-files-as-root/)

---

### CLI Text Editors

#### [Nano](https://www.nano-editor.org/)

```
sudo apt-get install nano
```

I don't know if Nano is installed on all the Ubuntu flavors, but it's installed on Ubuntu Unity, Ubuntu Gnome and Kubuntu as per my knowledge.
To open a file with nano use following command:

```
nano /path/to.file.txt
```

For more information about Nano, see [The Beginner’s Guide to Nano, the Linux Command-Line Text Editor](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42980/the-beginners-guide-to-nano-the-linux-command-line-text-editor/).

#### [Vim](http://www.vim.org/)

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

To open a file with Vim, type either of these two commands:

```
vim /path/to.file.txt
```

or

```
vi /path/to.file.txt
```

Vim (or at least vi) is installed by default on all Ubuntu (or any other Linux) flavor. If you start to like Vim and want it to have a user interface try [Gvim](https://askubuntu.com/a/862532/665251).  Also note that on some systems, `vi` is aliased to `vim`, so both commands do identical things. (which launching vim)

For more knowledge about vim, see [A Beginner's Guide to Vim](https://www.linux.com/learn/vim-101-beginners-guide-vim) or run `vimtutor` in the terminal.

---

*Keep in mind that QT apps don't look good on Gtk based desktop and vice versa. but if you want them to feel at home, try this question [How to make KDE applications look native in GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24780/how-to-make-kde-applications-look-native-in-gnome)*

---

[More Linux text editors](http://eastmanreference.com/the-almost-complete-list-of-linux-text-editors)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58649/discussion-on-answer-by-sumeet-deshmukh-what-are-the-default-text-editors-in-dif).

Comment: "if you want to edit files with root privileges, add gksu in front of a command" — Please use `gksudo` not `gksu`. They have a subtle but vital difference that can, in rare circumstances, lead to data loss. Documented on the [forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1819589),on this [site](https://askubuntu.com/a/288506/2088), and as a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gksu/+bug/1186676).

Comment: I don't know if I'd describe gvim as a user interface for vim as much as a way to run same old vim in a desktop window, so it basically just emulates a terminal window with vim in it.  It does add an optional menu whose options translate to key commands, as well as mouse support with context menu, true colour support, etc, but essentially the interface is the same as in text-mode.

Note that the version of vi installed by default is actually vim but may run vim in a "vi-compatible" mode.  You can't really get the "original vi" anymore in a Linux distro.

Comment: `vi` wasn't installed on my Google Cloud instance, a minimized Ubuntu 19.04 (disco dingo). It surprised me too.

Answer (score 33):

Flavors of Ubuntu can change all the time and so can the default GUI editors.  Instead of trying to remember all the default GUI editors of each distro, as long as the `xdg-utils` are installed you can run a simple command of [`xdg-open`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-xdg-open/) so you know what the default editor is and can launch it editing a text file:

```
xdg-open /path/to/textfile
```

`xdg-open` can also launch what the default audio player is when you open a .MP3 file.  Or if you want to quickly open a webpage you can use `xdg-open www.somewebsite.com` and it will launch your default web browser.

---

For the command line, `vi/vim` & `nano` seem to be the most common across Ubuntu flavors as being the default installed editors.  `vi/vim` should be in all flavors of Linux.

You can change the default command line editor with the following command then you can choose which one you want as your default:

For `sudo` or `root`:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

For your login:

```
update-alternatives --config editor
```

Example:

```
~$ update-alternatives --config editor
There are 9 choices for the alternative editor (providing /usr/bin/editor).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/vim.gnome   60        auto mode
  1            /bin/ed             -100       manual mode
  2            /bin/nano            40        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/emacs24     0         manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/mcedit      25        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/nvi         19        manual mode
  6            /usr/bin/nvim        30        manual mode
* 7            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        manual mode
  8            /usr/bin/vim.gnome   60        manual mode
  9            /usr/bin/vim.tiny    10        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Then since the command `/usr/bin/editor` should be in your path, to edit a file you can just run the following to edit your file:

```
editor /path/to/file
```

Or if you need elevated:

```
sudo editor /path/to/file
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i'll surely give that a try, seems like a timesaver

Comment: [Linux equivalent command for “open” command on Mac/Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/38984/241386), [Linux equivalent of the Mac OS X “open” command](http://stackoverflow.com/q/264395/995714)

Comment: IMHO this is the ideal answer. :-)

Comment: `$EDITOR` environmental variable is used to set your default CLI editor.

Comment: I don't like this answer. The default can be changed very quickly.

Comment: @Anwar: I think your argument actually supports Terrance's answer because `xdg-open` will continue to work despite changes to the default editor.

Comment: @DavidFoerster If one wants to know the actual editor so that he/she can recognize or learn or re-set to it, it won't help.

Comment: @Terrance In my opinion, it doesn't answer _what is default_

Comment: @Terrance I used `xdg-open` before and I know that it opens the set default. But that can be changed easily even by installing another application. For example, if you install another DE, it can be changed. Or OP can also change it at some point, so then `xdg-open` won't tell them the default text editor that was set by distribution. That's why I didn't like the answer, It was nothing personal. I suggest you to include this fact into the answer at least.

Comment: @Terrance Yes, it tells them what it is. But it won't tell them if it was default by distribution or not. That was the point

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58663/discussion-between-anwar-and-terrance).

Answer (score 15):

Kubuntu - kate

Lubuntu - leafpad

Xubuntu - mousepad

Ubuntu Gnome - gedit

Ubuntu MATE - pluma

Ubuntu Budgie -gedit

Ubuntu Kylin - gedit

Ubuntu Studio - mousepad

Comment: `kwrite` for a while as default text editor for Kubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Neither

```
xdg-open some_file
```

nor

```
$EDITOR some_file
```

is foolproof, unless you DEFINE "default" as whatever they invoke, which is not the sense in which it is commonly used.

For example, on my xenial systems:

I don't have a global EDITOR variable defined:

```
$ env | grep EDITOR
$ echo $EDITOR

$
```

So `$EDITOR some_file` fails completely in either a gui environment (x & openbox, in lxterminal), or in a tty.

In a gui environment `xdg-open some_file` opens the file in vi. In a plain tty, it ATTEMPTS to do the same, but fails. But vi is not my "default" editor in the sense the word is most commonly used. All the file managers I have installed agree that my default editor is `ed` (no, not THAT `ed` - if I were that masochistic I'd use `vi`, my `ed` is a script I wrote).

There may be a justification for defining "default" in terms of one or the other of those commands, but in the general usage of the great majority of users, "default" is an adjective applied to whatever program opens a file when you double or single click on it in a gui file browser (like Nautilus, Pcmanfm, Thunar, etc.), (double or single depending on the settings in that PARTICULAR file browser). Or, alternately, whatever program opens the file when you highlight it and press enter in an orthodox file browser like Midnight Commander.

So, in the most common usage of "default", you can have a different default for each file browser, and when you speak of default without qualification it means whatever is the default in the default file browser. And the default file browser in a graphical environment would be the one that opens if you double click on a directory (aka "folder") or a symlink to a directory on the desktop, or if you don't use the desktop metaphor, maybe the one most featured in a menu. As far as I know, in this sense, which is the normal real world usage, Sumeet Deshmukh's answer is totally correct and totally complete. It may be in the more abstract senses as well.

In a non-graphical environment, outside of an orthodox file manager, the common sense of the word "default", applied to an editor, has no normal application. Nobody working in tty invokes an editor with `xdg-open some_file` or `$EDITOR some_file` unless they are working on somebody else's machine, don't want to install anything, and have gotten desperate. They open an editor by directly invoking the one they want to open, BY NAME. If they get `bash: gedit: command not found` they try their second favorite, etc. What the default is, is irrelevant. All that matters is their preferences and what's installed or can be installed.

#### The Main Point:

> . . . gksu gedit /path/file.txt which wont work because gedit isn't the default text editor . . . .

Wrong. And that's why I posted, to explain why that statement is wrong and why that command failed. What the default editor is, however you define it, is irrelevant.

For that command to work, you need 2 things:

- Both programs, `gksu` and `gedit`, must be installed on the system.
- You must have suitable permissions for the file and it's ancestral directories. You have to have x on all directories in the path, at least r on the file itself, and probably at least r on the parent directory. Some editors might require w on the file or even on the parent directory, although they shouldn't.

You should be able to tell why the command failed by reading the error message. If you like gedit, install it.

But gksu is dangerous. Use gksudo if you need it. But don't use any of the su/sudo/gksu/gksudo/pkexec type commands unless the command that follows fails without it. And even then, only if it SHOULD have failed. If it should have worked, using some sudo-ish command to MAKE it work is like "If it don't fit, get a bigger hammer". It will create more problems down the road. In that case, correct the permissions , and try to figure why they were wrong in the first place.

Nor are any of the sudo type commands omnipotent. Sometimes, you MUST change permissions before you can edit the file even WITH gksudo.

Regarding the dangers of `gksu` listen to Paddy who commented on Sumeet's answer. He is wise chap who has been around a while. Repeating his 3 links:

```
https://askubuntu.com/a/288506/2088
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gksu/+bug/1186676
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1819589
```

Comment: Could you justify your assertion that gksu is evil?

Comment: @Zanna Paddy already did, in his comment after Sumeet's answer. Check out all 3 of his links. The middle one https://askubuntu.com/a/288506/2088 is probably the clearest.

Comment: at least put a link in your answer then. You cannot assume everyone is reading the whole page or even that other answers will remain static. Anyway, gksu and gksudo are unnecessary imho

Comment: "gksu and gksudo are unnecessary" - Maybe if you are substituting pkexec. I haven't studied  it.  But plain sudo isn't an adequate substitute.

Comment: we are "meant to" use `sudo -i` and then launch the program, or you can just use `sudo -H`. I don't use GUI text editors. I don't use the GUI for much, but I use `sudo -i` for anything I can't use `sudo` for

Comment: @Zanna should I edit my answer to use `sudo i`, why not `gksudo`? everybody seems to be recommending that.

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh that's up to you, but `gksu` is not installed by default, while `sudo` is of course. Sometimes you need root permissions to fix an APT problem, so installing a package is not practicable. Many people who are used to gksu still install it and use it, but it's the "old fashioned way" I guess :) I would use `sudo -H gedit` for example (I go around editing that `-H` into posts!) because really you need extra steps with `sudo -i`: some programs don't start in one step like that, and you have to remind people to exit the root shell, so `sudo -H` is the easiest way

Comment: @Zanna Thnks. I know -H. I'll look up -i in the man. You do save installing 1 package I suppose. But gksudo is shorter & easier to type.  Those little finger characters on the upper row are the source of most of my typos. Oh. I'll never catch up with a demon-typist if she revises while I slowly grind out my answer to the previous version ;-)

Comment: I think `gksu` and `gksudo` was installed by default on Ubuntu Gnome

Comment: @LewRockwellFan apart from this topic, your answer seems to be really good, but it's not understandable, maybe I lack in knowledge but can you make it little bit more beginners friendly  and it's TL;TR (Opinion)

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh  Correct. Gksu and gksudo sort of have to be installed by default, and not just in Gnome - because they are part  of the same package. At least so saith synaptic in Xenial. And they sure aren't going to leave out gksudo.  Almost certainly installed by default in all the standard variants. BTW, I began my answer saying you should get the check  mark, but  . . . ahem . . . SOMEBODY edited that  out.  I admit I was prolix.

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh It isn't clear to me what you are asking me to clarify. My whole post? Some part?

Comment: @LewRockwellFan that part had to get removed, Zanna is amazing at what they do. but other than that If you can improve it in some ways, try to do it in free time, but I think it serves the purpose as it is

Comment: FYI [Why is gksu no longer installed by default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/284306/why-is-gksu-no-longer-installed-by-default) cc @SumeetDeshmukh :)

Comment: @Zanna is it just gone from Ubuntu Unity or all flavors, cause I do not remember installing it || reading the link

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh maybe they put it back! I seem to have it in MATE now. I am pretty sure I didn't in 16.04

Comment: @Zanna maybe some choices are made by Flavor maintainers || eg `Universe` and `Multiverse`  repos are already enabled in Ubuntu Gnome and Kubuntu (I've just tried those two)

Comment: @Zanna Or pulled in unnoticed as a dependency. It is NOT on the big Xenial manifest: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xenial/daily-live/current/xenial-desktop-amd64.manifest I'm shocked. If I had a half-penny for every exclamation point I've seen after strident exhortations to use gksudo, not sudo, I'd be . . . well, at least able to start an old coin shop. And I just KNEW I was omniscient.

Comment: I'm using 17.04 FYI, that's why I said "maybe they put it back" - my omniscience is a bit rusty