# What are the different default application in different Ubuntu flavours?

Tags: default-programs

I have installed Ubuntu MATE and Ubuntu with Unity.

In Ubuntu with Unity, there is Nautilus file manager, Gedit text editor, and others.

In Ubuntu MATE, there is the file manager Caja, Pluma a text editor and additional software. Such as Synapse, gdebi package installer as well as others.

What are the different default applications in other Ubuntu flavors?

Comment: What problem will this information help you solve?

Comment: @user535733 sir,i have not any problem to solved but the reason for asking this question is my curiosity and if we visit the askubutnu's about us section ,there is a line which includes "sharing knowledge" and i cant find this information else where too.thus i posted this question.  sorry for any misbehavior.your friendly

Comment: @SMITPATIL there is nothing wrong with curiosity but answer scope to this question would be **Too Broad**  and such questions aren't allowed here at ask ubuntu. but if you try to limit the scope of your question then it can get some [pretty good answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913609/what-are-the-default-text-editors-in-different-flavours-of-ubuntu/913637#913637)

Comment: Just head over to the respective site and the lovely pages would tell it to you will attractive screenshots and more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily find them by looking at each flavor's Wikipedia page. Here are the applications included in the four most popular Ubuntu flavors:

#### Lubuntu

> - Abiword – word processor
> - Audacious – music player
> - Evince – PDF reader
> - File-roller – archiver
> - Firefox – web browser
> - Galculator – calculator
> - GDebi – package installer
> - GNOME Software – package manager
> - Gnumeric – spreadsheet
> - Guvcview – webcam
> - LightDM – log-in manager
> - Light-Locker – screen locker
> - MPlayer – video player
> - MTPaint – graphics painting
> - Pidgin – instant messenger and microblogging
> - Scrot – screenshot tool
> - Simple Scan – scanning
> - Sylpheed – email client
> - Synaptic and Lubuntu Software Center – package managers
> - Transmission – bittorrent client
> - Update Manager
> - Startup Disk Creator – USB ISO writer
> - Wget – command line webpage downloader
> - XChat – IRC
> - Xfburn – CD burner
> - Xpad – notetaking

[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu)

#### Xubuntu

> - Catfish - desktop search
> - Common Unix Printing System - printer utility and PDF creator
> - Evince - PDF reader
> - Firefox - web browser
> - GIMP - graphics editor
> - LibreOffice Calc - spreadsheet
> - LibreOffice Writer - word processor
> - Mousepad - text editor
> - Orage - calendar
> - Parole - media player
> - Pidgin - internet messenger
> - Thunderbird - e-mail client
> - XChat - IRC client
> - Simple Scan - scanner utilities

[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xubuntu#Applications)

Thunar as file manager as I know

#### Kubuntu

- Okular - pdf viewer
- Gwenview - image viewer
- KSnapshot - desktop screenshots.
- Firefox is the default browser shipped with Kubuntu
- Kmail as mail client
- Kate - editor
- Ark - archive manager
- Konsole - terminal
- Dolphin - filemanager

[source + more info](https://userbase.kde.org/Kubuntu/Software)

#### ubuntu mate

- pluma - text editor
- caja- file manager
- synapse- serch tool
- welcome - introduce the OS and to download softwares
- galculator - calculator
- gdebi packadge installer - package installer
- mate terminal - terminal
- atril document viewer - document viewer
- mate dictonary - dictionary
- Eye of MATE - image viewer
- vlc media player - to play videos
- Disk Usage Analyzer -A graphical tool to analyze disk usage
- dconf editor -low level configuration system and settings management
- Firefox - web browser